# how do I clear SHELL history upon logout in TCSH Shell?

Tags: tcsh

How do I clear SHELL history in TCSH upon exiting SHELL?

I tried to put history -c in .logout but it didn't work.

Please advice.

Thank you.
PA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clearing the history, not saving it would be a better option.

You can set the number of lines saved in the `savehist` variable or set the `histfile` to `/dev/null` or something.

Answer (score 0):

End the session with

```
kill -9 $$
```